# C++11 struct before return type

Tags: c++, c++11

In one place I found the following code:

a.h

```
struct foo {
...
}
```

---

b.cpp

```
struct foo make_foo(){
...
}
```

I've checked and the code works perfectly well without the 'struct' before the function return type. What is the purpose of it ?

Thanks,
Orwe

Comment: There is none. It is a C-ism.

Comment: In C++ you don't have to write `struct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C code, the `struct` is needed to refer to the type; `foo` is not enough. It's not required, but doesn't break, in C++.

This is why you will often see C code write something like:

```
typedef struct foo
{
} foo;

// This now works - foo is a complete type defined to be struct foo
foo make_foo()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a C relict. It's redundant in C++, but it still compiles for backward compatibility.